# How to perform regex in find function of javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object

This is my Object:

```
let temp = [{
    "title": "Student Details",
    "education": "under graduate",
    "studentId": "xyz202267"
},
{
    "title": "Student details",
    "education": "under graduate",
    "studentId": "xyz202234"
}]
```

I want to compare the input title with title in temp.
I want to do something like this:

```
let input = 'studentdetails'
const ans = temp.find(obj => obj.title.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase() === input)
```

I know this won't work because we are trying to replace the orignal Object during run time. Is there something I can do to make this work?

Comment: It works in my side and you had better to use `Array.filter()` instead

Comment: What does not work? What exactly are you trying to find. One or both?

Comment: @epascarello I was not doing the same check elsewhere that's why I was getting an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working,but in order to get all the results that meets the requirements,you need to use `Array.filter()` instead of `Array.find()`

```js
let temp = [{
    "title": "Student Details",
    "education": "under graduate",
    "studentId": "xyz202267"
},
{
    "title": "Student details",
    "education": "under graduate",
    "studentId": "xyz202234"
}]


let input = 'studentdetails'
const ans = temp.filter(obj => obj.title.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase() === input)
console.log(ans)
```

Comment: I checked it again, there was a dependency code in other part of the program, that was the reason I was getting an error. Thank you for letting me know